# C++ Try Catch Block does not catch an exception

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I am a beginner in C++ and trying to create a simple console program that calculates the 'm' and 'b' of a linear equation... to parse the input double that the user provides, I am using a stringstream and using a try-catch block to check for false inputs.  A persistent error keeps following even though the catch block has a global exception [Unhandled exception at 0x74c8b9bc in Equation Solver.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..]

```
double XOne;`enter code here`
double YOne;
double XTwo;
double YTwo;
bool inputCheck = false;
while (inputCheck == false)
{
    Clear();
    WriteLine("**Linear Equation**");
    Write("X1: ");
    string xone = ReadLine();
    Write("Y1: ");
    string yone = ReadLine();
    Write("X2: ");
    string xtwo = ReadLine();
    Write("Y2: ");
    string ytwo = ReadLine();
    try
    {
        stringstream s1(xone);
        if (s1 >> XOne) { s1 >> XOne; } else { throw; }
        stringstream s2(yone); // consider I give an invalid input for this variable
        if (s2 >> YOne) { s2 >> YOne; } else { throw; } // this doesn't solve the problem
        stringstream s3(xtwo);
        if (s3 >> XTwo) { s3 >> XTwo; } else { throw; }
        stringstream s4(ytwo);
        if (s4 >> YTwo) { s4 >> YTwo; } else { throw; }
    }
    catch (...) { WriteLine("Invalid Input"); ReadLine(); }
}

LinearEquation equation;
equation.Initialize(XOne, YOne, XTwo, YTwo);
stringstream s5;
s5 << equation.m;
string m = s5.str();
stringstream s6;
s6 << equation.b;
string b = s6.str();
Write("Y = ");
Write(m);
Write("X + ");
WriteLine(b);
ReadLine();
```

**EDIT**
The first suggestion worked like a charm... Thank you!
This is the code after I modified it according to the reviewer.

```
double XOne;
double YOne;
double XTwo;
double YTwo;
bool inputCheck = false;
while (inputCheck == false)
{
    Clear();
    WriteLine("**Linear Equation**");
    Write("X1: ");
    string xone = ReadLine();
    Write("Y1: ");
    string yone = ReadLine();
    Write("X2: ");
    string xtwo = ReadLine();
    Write("Y2: ");
    string ytwo = ReadLine();
    try
    {
        stringstream s1(xone);
        if (s1 >> XOne) { s1 >> XOne; } else { throw runtime_error("Invalid Input"); }
        stringstream s2(yone);
        if (s2 >> YOne) { s2 >> YOne; } else { throw runtime_error("Invalid Input"); }
        stringstream s3(xtwo);
        if (s3 >> XTwo) { s3 >> XTwo; } else { throw runtime_error("Invalid Input"); }
        stringstream s4(ytwo);
        if (s4 >> YTwo) { s4 >> YTwo; } else { throw runtime_error("Invalid Input"); }
    }
    catch (runtime_error e) { WriteLine(e.what()); ReadLine(); }
}

LinearEquation equation;
equation.Initialize(XOne, YOne, XTwo, YTwo);
stringstream s5;
s5 << equation.m;
string m = s5.str();
stringstream s6;
s6 << equation.b;
string b = s6.str();
Write("Y = ");
Write(m);
Write("X + ");
WriteLine(b);
ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`throw` without an argument can only be used when there is an exception being handled (i.e. in a catch block or a function called directly or indirectly from a catch block), otherwise you have to use throw with an argument which is usually an exception object of some sort.

If `throw` is executed when an exception is not being handled `std::terminate` will be called to end your program.

e.g. (after `#include <stdexcept>`)

```
throw std::runtime_error("Bad input");
```